# Not able to disable tooltip nvD3.js

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, nvd3.js

I am trying to disable tooltip from the discrete bar chart which is the most easiest thing to do. But still its not working. 
I tried chart.tooltip(false), but it gives chart.tooltip function not defined console error. And because i am using plain nvD3 and not angular-nvD3 directives, if I use interactive(false), it gets ignored.

I did installed nvD3 using bower, is that the reason for it acting that way. am i missing any of the library required for the tooltip? please help.

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="_assets/bower/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css")
script(src="_assets/bower/d3/d3.js")
script(src="_assets/bower/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

`chart.tooltip(false)`

do

`chart.tooltips(false)` //this is deprecated

`chart.tooltip.enabled(false)`//this is latest

example [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html)

doc [refer](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#tooltip)